# PaintCode 2 crashes on start

Tags: macos, vmware, paintcode

All my apps work fine but this new installed paint code crashes on start, so I cant even use it.

```
log here http://pastebin.com/ZS4a2whE
```

What could i do? Is it because of VMWare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSX inside Vmware has some serious limitations  in terms of graphics (3D acceleration) and paintcode relies on these features which VMWare does not provide inside a OSX Guest OS.

Not just paintcode, if you noticed, even keynote/iWork will not work as expected.
We only hope further versions of vmware comes with 3D acceleration for OSX Guest.